# Serve ionic app on android with specified port

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-emulator

I want to serve my ionic 5 app on Android emulator. I'm using `ionic cordova run android` command. The problem is that my API has CORS set to allow localhost:4200 and I'm getting CORS error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at '...' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

How can I specify a port? Opions like `--port=4200`, `-p 4200` not working.

Comment: Hey @SigGP, did you already find any answer for this?